# Trying to Import OpenCV 4.8 in Android Studio Giraffe

Tags: android, opencv, gradle

I have seen this question asked multiple times, but they are for much older versions of OpenCV or Android Studio, and the solutions haven't worked for me.

I'm trying to get the OpenCV SDK installed as a module in my project so I can start using it.  Here is what I've done so far:

First, I created a new Android project.  It targets Android 28 and has a blank activity.  The app starts in an emulator.

I downloaded the latest Android SDK from the OpenCV site and unzipped it.

In Android Studio, I did file->new->import module
I selected the folder C:\dev\opencv\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk

Some tutorials say to select the Java folder under sdk, but the latest one I am following said to select just \sdk

Once the module is selected and imported, I get a build error

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

I assume it has some problem with the build.gradle that comes with the OpenCV sdk.  Here is that file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

def openCVersionName = "4.8.0"
def openCVersionCode = ((4 * 100 + 8) * 100 + 0) * 10 + 0

println "OpenCV: " +openCVersionName + " " + project.buildscript.sourceFile

android {
    
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26

        versionCode openCVersionCode
        versionName openCVersionName

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                targets "opencv_jni_shared"
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packagingOptions {
                doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
            }
        }
        release {
            packagingOptions {
                doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['native/libs']
            java.srcDirs = ['java/src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['java/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['java/res']
            manifest.srcFile 'java/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path (project.projectDir.toString() + '/libcxx_helper/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Any ideas what I should try next?  I'm not an Android build expert.  I have done OpenCV in Python and have built Android apps using Flutter.  So this is my first try with Android native code.

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to add the OpenCV library to a starter project and have it build correctly.  Here is what I had to do:

1. Change the gradle file that comes with OpenCV.  Add this code in the android {} section.  I made up the namespace name

```
    namespace "org.opencv.androidsdk"
```

Added this to my gradle settings file at the very end

```
include(":opencv")
project(":opencv").projectDir = File("C:\\dev\\opencv\\OpenCV-android-sdk\\sdk")
```

I did this instead of importing the module as I tried in my original question.

I'm beginning to think there is a conspiracy to prevent newbies from doing mobile OpenCV.  The information is very hard to find, is old, outdated, and often wrong.  I suppose it's because of all the tech layoffs.  People need to keep being needed, so the best way to do that is to mislead others trying to do the same job as theirs. :)

Hope this helps someone.  My next hurdle will be to actually call some OpenCV in my sample project.